# Talend tFileInputDelimited Advanced Setting --> "Check each row structure against schema"

Tags: talend

Can anyone please explain the difference of having the field "Check each row structure against schema" checked and unchecked in the Advanced Setting of tFileInputDelimited.

I tried to read a csv file as input and a tFileOutputDelimited with the options checked and unchecked, but there was no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your file is valid, meaning the structure of your rows is that defined in your schema, that's why you don't see a difference whether the option is checked or unchecked.
Now consider this sample file :

```
id;name;state
1;abraham;NY
2;jeff
3;thomas
```

You can see that rows 2 and 3 do not have a valid structure, yet when I run my job Talend doesn't complain (with `Check each row structure against schema` **unchecked**):

[image]

It just reads all it can.

Now with `Check each row structure against schema` **checked** :

[image]

I get a nice little warning in the console saying that 2 rows have missing columns. Those rows can be captured using a `Reject` link on the `tFileInputDelimited` :

[image]

Another benefit of `Check each row structure against schema` option, is you can stop job execution if you have invalid rows. Just check "Die on error" in the basic settings tab of `tFileInputDelimited` (But doing that prevents you from using the `Reject` link).